# Any way to make nicknames appear rather than full names?

Tags: contacts

When creating contacts, you can enter nicknames. Is there a way to make these nicknames appear when your contacts call/text you as opposed to their full names?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Apple hasn't given us that feature. As you probably already noticed the only place it displays is in the contact listing itself.

Comment: Ah right, no worries - at least I know for sure now. :-)

Comment: Maybe they will add that iOS 6? (I kind of doubt it though).

Comment: Not yet. Even in iOS 13.x

Answer (score 1):

Jailbroken users can opt to install [Nickname from Cydia.](http://cydiasources.org/nickname/)

Answer (score -1):

Enter their nickname in the company space. Then list them as a company. It will bold the name in your contacts list. From then on they will show up as their nickname.